# Mysql Query takes more than 300 seconds

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two MYSQL tables, A and B. Table A has 44,902 rows and table B has 109,583 rows.
I would like to compare two columns from the two tables and return the rows from table A where it finds a match. My, unsuccessful queries are:

```
SELECT pool.domain_name FROM `pool`, `en_dict` WHERE pool.domain_string = en_dict.word
```

and another variant:

```
SELECT a.domain_name FROM `pool` as a inner join en_dict as b  on a.domain_string = b.word
```

both solutions falied returning any values under 300 seconds.

What should I do to reduce the time for finding the matches??

P.S. I have tried adding a LIMIT at the end of the queries and managed to display 10 results in 245 seconds.

Edit: My tables structures are as follows :

```
--
-- Table structure for table `en_dict`
--

CREATE TABLE `en_dict` (
  `word_id` bigint(20) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`word_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=109584 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `pool`
--

CREATE TABLE `pool` (
  `domain_id` bigint(20) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `domain_tld` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `domain_string` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `domain_lenght` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `domain_expiretime` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=44903 ;
```

Comment: Do you have keys defined on your tables?

Comment: Kindly list your table structure ..

Comment: Did you index `pool.domain_string` and `en_dict.word`?

Comment: I have tried to run the query once more and it's still loading (mysql is kind of dead now) and I cannot export the exact structure from phpmyadmin but I think I can reproduce it:

Table en_dict has the following structure:
id / unsigned / primary key / auto_increment;
word / varchar(100) ;


Table pool has the structure as follows:
pool_id / unsigned/ primary_key / auto_increment;
pool_domain varchar (80)
pool_string varchar (70)
pool_date date
pool_tld varchar (5)

Comment: If you add an index on the columns mentioned above it should perform much better. Also, please edit your question and add the information about your tables there. It's clearer than adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an index on the relevant columns of your tables:

```
ALTER TABLE `pool` ADD INDEX `domain_string_idx` (`domain_string`);
ALTER TABLE `en_dict` ADD INDEX `word_idx` (`word`);
```

Comment: I added a little note about the EXPLAIN keyword.

Comment: @JoãoSimões, it seems your edit was rejected (not by me). It may be better to add such remarks as a comment instead of an edit in the future.

Comment: No problem, I'll add it here:

@AngelinCalu if you face similar problems in the future, I recommend the use of EXPLAIN keyword. For a detailed explanation you can visit the following url: http://schimpf.es/mysql-explain-tutorial/

Comment: @JoãoSimões, Thanks for the tip, it was very well received.